# How do I match a quoted string followed by a string in curly brackets?

Tags: java, regex, expression, brackets

I need a regex expression for matching a string in quotes and then a white space then a round bracket then a curly bracket.

For example this is the text I want to match in Java:

```
"'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {A Barrel Full of Airmen (#7.7)}
```

What would the regex for this be?

Sorry, but I'm just really lost. I tried a lot of different things but now I'm so stumped.

Comment: "(.*)" \(([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\) \{(.*)\}

Answer (score 3):

`"[^"]*"\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{[^}]*\}`

Comment: this will fail if the title contains double-quotes :)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"\\s+\\((\\d{4})\\)\\s+\\{(.*?)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"'Allo 'Allo!\" (1982) {A Barrel Full of Airmen (#7.7)}");
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
  System.out.println(m.group(2));
  System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
"'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {A Barrel Full of Airmen (#7.7)}
'Allo 'Allo!
1982
A Barrel Full of Airmen (#7.7)
```

Comment: could be more selective on the year (4 digits) to avoid false matches in the case of ill-behaved input

Comment: you mean as your entire original line, i.e. `m.group(0)`?

Comment: oh wow thanks so much guys it works but no i have to make sure it works for my whole text file which is about 20Mb lol but thanks a lot.

Comment: hey cletus could you help me in my other question please

Answer (score 0):

"[^"]+"\s([^)]+)\s{[^}]+}